# Dropzone.js preview addedimage elsewhere on the page

Tags: javascript, filereader, dropzone.js

Does anyone know how to access image file added to dropzone before it is being uploaded, so it can be displayed in another div in the page?

Thanks

Comment: Why was it downvoted? It seems like a legitimate question and I'm eager to see an answer.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but we ended up just using the same div class that belongs to dropzone's own preview and blow its size up else where.

Comment: In the lack of a better answer I'd suggest posting it as a viable answer and accepting it.